# Increasing the HDFS Disk size in HDP 2.3 3 node cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

In the 3 node cluster installation for POC, My 3rd note is DataNode, it has a disk space of about 200 GB. As per the ambari's HDFS Disk Usage widget my current HDFS usage is as follows:

DFS Used: 512.8 MB (1.02%); 
non DFS used 8.1 GB (16.52%); 
remaining 40.4GB (82.46 %)

When I do df -h to check the disk size I can see a lot of space is taken by tmpfs as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

How can I use that space for my HDFS. My node 3 has 200 GB Hard disk space

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the tmpfs partition e.g.:

```
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=32g tmpfs /mnt/dn-tmpfs/
```

Then to use this mounted partition in hdfs you can configure it `hdfs-site.xml` as data directory e.g.

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
  <value>/grid/0,/grid/1,/grid/2,[RAM_DISK]/mnt/dn-tmpfs</value>
</property>
```

for more detail refer: [Choosing tmpfs (vs ramfs)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/MemoryStorage.html)

EDIT: I could not see the property 'datanode.data.dir' in my ambari setup. If you want, it can be added using Ambari GUI as:

HDFS -> Configs -> Custom hdfs-site -> Add Property ...